# Should constant details be part of the abstraction or the implementation?

Tags: java, oop

I have a SaveSettings network operation in my application.
I am using an adapter so that I can be free to plug in another networking library in the future and not change any of my code.

```
public interface SaveSettingsOnServerAdapter {
    void saveSettings(User user, OnSaveSettingsOnServerListener listener);
}

public class SaveSettingsOnServerAdapterImpl implements SaveSettingsOnServerAdapter {

    private static final String API_USER_SESSION_HEADER = "Cookie";
    private static final String API_SAVE_SETTINGS_PATH = "user/{user_id}/update";
    private static final String API_SAVE_SETTINGS_USER_ID_PATH_PARAMETER = "user_id";
    private static final String API_SAVE_SETTINGS_SYNC_WITH_CALENDAR_PARAMETER = "sync_with_calendar";
    private static final String API_SAVE_SETTINGS_USE_MOBILE_NETWORK_PARAMETER = "use_mobile_network";



    @Override
    void saveSettings(User user, OnSaveSettingsOnServerListener listener) {
        // Some implementation here, in my case - RETROFIT
    }


}
```

My gut feeling tells me that those details outlined in the constants defined in the Implementation class are independent of whatever networking library I choose to use for the networking, so they should be part of the abstraction, right?

If so, should I declare `SaveSettingsOnNetworkAdapter` abstract and insert them there? And then `SaveSettingsOnNetworkAdapterImpl` extend it instead of implement it? Is it a problem to extend an abstract class instead of implementing an interface when employing the Adapter pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading an interface to an abstract class isn't unproblematic. You force all future implementations to extend that class and only that class, whereas currently you can attach the interface to almost anything.

Plus, the parameters may be constant (as far as you can tell now) but is it really the responsibility of a `SaveSettingsOnServerAdapter` to keep & define them?

They are required in there for sure. But requirements can be provided by other places as well. The most versatile / abstract solution to that is to define another interface that provides the values and to add the dependency to that interface to the constructor of every `SaveSettingsOnServerAdapter` implementation.

If you don't like to repeat that constructor, that would be a good place to make an abstract class that implements `SaveSettingsOnServerAdapterImpl` and covers the common code to deal with the external interface.

But it's up to you. Whether you want more encapsulation and to which degree you want that depends on what you're working on. In a tiny tool that isn't going to change is pointless since abstractions aim to make change easy. And more abstraction also means more code and more code means more places that can break.

```
public interface ServerConfiguration {
    String getHeader();
    String getPath();
    ...
}

public enum DefaultServerConfiguration implements ServerConfiguration {
    INSTANCE;
    private static final String API_USER_SESSION_HEADER = "Cookie";
    private static final String API_SAVE_SETTINGS_PATH = "user/{user_id}/update";
    ...

    @Override
    public String getHeader() {
        return API_SAVE_SETTINGS_PATH;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return API_SAVE_SETTINGS_PATH;
    }
    ...
}
public class SaveSettingsOnServerAdapterImpl implements SaveSettingsOnServerAdapter {

    private final ServerConfiguration config;
    public SaveSettingsOnServerAdapterImpl(ServerConfiguration config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    void saveSettings(User user, OnSaveSettingsOnServerListener listener) {
        new Request().withHeader(config.getHeader());
    }

}

public class UserOfAllThis {
    new SaveSettingsOnServerAdapterImpl(DefaultServerConfiguration.INSTANCE);
}
```

Comment: You mean I should define an interface filled with constant values? And then create an implementation of it and pass it to the constructor of the adapter implementation? Can I define them in a concrete class and add it as a member of the adapter implementation or would that be bad? I am aiming for maximum abstraction here because I am doing this for leaning design patterns, and not because I expect change

Comment: @J.K. made an example. Now the `SaveSettingsOnServerAdapterImpl` is completely shielded from configuration changes. You can even decide to load settings dynamically from a database (and implement a `DatabaseBackedServerConfiguration`) without this class noticing. In other words, the class has 1 less reason to change: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! It even uses the single-element enum type singleton that I've been reading for

Comment: @J.K. Hehe, OO can be fun sometimes but I think in practice, I would have probably left the code as you had in the beginning. There is always a thing you can abstract a little more and make a little nicer but you can also go too far you end up with https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition

Answer (score 1):

The idea of abstraction is to make your code more generic. This should hide implementation as much as possible. Adding constants to the abstract layer will reveal some implementation details. The best way will probably be to add the constants to the implementation class or create a new class with these constants.

Comment: If I decide to put them in a separate class (which I am not leaning towards) is there a convention of how should I name the class and in which package should I put it?

Comment: I don't think there is a convention for this. I see a lot of `API_SAVE_SETTINGS*`, so why not class `ApiSaveSettings`, with constant like `PATH` , `USER_ID_PATH_PARAMETER`, etc.